# Can I call the unserialize function in "Select Operation" of Yii2 Active Query

Tags: php, sql, yii2

In my database table, the list of winners is stored in a serialized way. I know that after fetching the winners record from the database, I can unserialize the data and make an array of it. But for that, I have to use, "foreach" loop or have to do it manually. And I have successfully done that too. 
But a thing came to my mind that is this possible to get the data in an unserialized way during the execution of query. Below is my Yii2 Active Query.

```
$winners = Winners::find()
        ->select('winners')
        ->where(['event_id'=> Yii::$app->session->get('event_id')])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

This query is giving me what I want. Let me show you.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [winners] => a:10:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:8;i:3;i:13;i:4;i:15;i:5;i:19;i:6;i:20;i:7;i:23;i:8;i:25;i:9;i:26;}
    )
```

**But I want the winners list in unserialized form. And I tried doing the following.**

```
$winners = Winners::find()
        ->select(serialize('winners'))
        ->where(['event_id'=> Yii::$app->session->get('event_id')])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

**But the above query generates an error. Is there any way to Unserialize the winners list during the query execution and get the winners list in array format**

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: I am getting "Column not found"

Comment: You want the result in unserialized form, so why are you querying it in serialize

Comment: It's a typo. I meant to write Unserialize.

Comment: You can't. ActiveQuery is for loading data from DB to model, not for modifying them. And the `serialize()` is php function, the DB doesn't know how the data has been serialized so you can't unserialize it in DB with SQL query. You can let the data load into model and unserialize them in afterFind callback. You can make some class with method that would wrap the query and unserialize the data before returning result. Or you can create own class that would extend ActiveQuery, override it's `all()` method to unserialize data and override `Winners::find()` to use your class instead of ActiveQuery.

Comment: Thank you @MichalHynčica. I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$winners = Winners::find()
        ->select('winners')
        ->where(['event_id'=> Yii::$app->session->get('event_id')])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();

$result = unserialize($winners[0]['winners']);
```

Now use $result.

Comment: It's a manual approach to unserialize the winners list. I want to write the Unserialize function in the "Select" operation. So that,  the winners list would be an array. 
I want something like, Select ('winners') as Unserialize('winners'). Somewhat like this approach so that the column Winner automatically gets unserialized.